# Gradient on Mesh Question

Tags: materials, uv

I am have a question about the gradient. I have 2 mesh but the gradients acting differently, and dont know how to fix the problem. As you see the other mesh is not gradient but divided in half. When I am doing the UV unwrap, the gradient even look weirder and I cannot control how it should go linear. Thank you for your help!

[image]

[image]